# VB.NET Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'WebBrowser'

Tags: .net, vb.net

I keep getting this really annoying error in VB.NET Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'WebBrowser'

It doesnt output the error all the time... Only sometimes and I tried to change some settings in the application but that didn't help.

The line with the exception is the second to the bottom.

Here's my code:

```html
Dim web as string = "Link to the website" 
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            If txtUser.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Please enter a Username!")
            ElseIf txtPass.Text = "" Then

                MsgBox("Please enter a Password!")
            Else
                For Each www As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.All
                    If www.GetAttribute("name").ToLower = "submit" Then
                        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user").SetAttribute("value", txtUser.Text)
                        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", txtPass.Text)
                        www.InvokeMember("click")
                        Timer7.Start()
                    End If


                Next
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer7_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer7.Tick
        Try
            If WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText.Contains("ERROR") Then
                Timer7.Stop()
                MessageBox.Show("Username & Password are incorrect!")
                WebBrowser1.Navigate(web)
            ElseIf WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText.Contains("VALID") Then

                Timer7.Stop()
                Statuscheck()


            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(web)
    End Sub
```

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: A very helpful piece of information would be which line the exception occurs on if you know or can find out.

Comment: The line with the exception is the second to the bottom. @TonyHinkle

Comment: If it happens intermittently it may be a timing issue since that is on form load and everything may not be spun up yet.  Put a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` before that line and see if the problem still occurs.  If it only happens once every 100 times that may be a pain to test, but if it's once every 5 times that wouldn't be too bad...

Comment: I tried the that but it doesn't seem to do anything to the application. I would say it throws the exception every 2 times I launch it. If I get luck it's 3 or 4 times. @TonyHinkle

Comment: Also the problem isnt that line of code... I took that line out and something else is causing it... Now its not even giving an error.

Comment: Does the error really just say "WebBrowser" or does it say "WebBrowser1"?  That is pretty important as there is no object named WebBrowser referenced in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Alright... I figured it all out and the problem is earlier today I pulled out my Ethernet cable and my dns settings were now screwed up. One of the webrequests I didn't post in the code had a ssl/tsl certificate problem. I restarted my computer and now it's fixed. Im still curious about why it throw the wrong exception.

Here is how I found the problem. So On the webrequest sub there was a try event and that had a error message if there was a exception. The whole time that particular exception was going off and I didn't know. I took apart the application and took out the try events. It was now giving the RIGHT exception. Like I said I fixed it. Sorry for the people that had to take time into thinking about this for me :)